# I'm trying to get bulk data from Europe PMC annotations api in python

Tags: python, json, api, data-annotations, europepmc

my code is

if **name** == '**main**':
json_data=requests.get("https://www.ebi.ac.uk/europepmc/annotations_api/annotationsByArticleIds?articleIds=PMC%3A4771370&section=Abstract&provider=Europe%20PMC&format=JSON").content
r=json.loads(json_data)
df = json_to_dataframe(r)
print(df)

My only problem is how can run this for multiple IDs, like i have atleast thousands of ids in a file.
Please help I'm using python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know Python and can get all the IDs from the file into a list `article_ids`, you can use the following script:

```py
URL = 'https://www.ebi.ac.uk/europepmc/annotations_api/annotationsByArticleIds'

article_ids = ['PMC:4771370']

for article_id in article_ids:
    params = {
        'articleIds': article_id,
        'section': 'Abstract',
        'provider': 'Europe PMC',
        'format': 'JSON'
    }
    json_data = requests.get(URL, params=params).content
    r = json.loads(json_data)
    df = json_to_dataframe(r)
    print(df)
```

Comment: hi sidharth,i have updated the info in the question, can you please see again.

Comment: thanks sidharth, can you also tell me how can i open my file, because i'm using readlines which is not giving the results.

Comment: @Arvind, perhaps a [Python tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/python-open-file-how-to-read-a-text-file-line-by-line/) can help.

Comment: @sidhartha already tried that, maybe i'm implementing wrong, can you help?

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing the shared URL and reading the [URL Encodings article](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP),
I observed that each value of annotationByArticleIDs has format of SOURCE:EXTERNAL_ID format.

TEST1:
If you hit the url:

```
https://www.ebi.ac.uk/europepmc/annotations_api/annotationsByArticleIds?articleIds=PMC
```

**Output is:**
It must contain values with format SOURCE:EXTERNAL_ID where SOURCE must have one of the following values [PMC, MED, PAT, AGR, CBA, HIR, CTX, ETH, CIT, PPR, NBK] and EXTERNAL_ID must be a number when SOURCE=PMC

- Above output shows possible list of sources
- Each source is separated by EXTERNAL_ID using colon
- Colon is represented by %3A in URL Encoding article
- In order to separate one pair of value from another value, you could use comma operator
- Comma is represented using %2C in the same URL encoding article

ANSWER: So to fetch multiple articles you could generate string of article ids in the format SOURCE1:EXTERNAL_ID1,SOURCE2:EXTERNAL_ID2 .... SOURCE3:EXTERNAL_ID3 and append in the main url

Few Limitations:

- Max URL Length could be 2048 characters
- Depending upon possible ids, you will be able to fetch around 150 to 200 articles
- You could loop over a batch of 150 and then fetch the required information

Comment: is it'll be a good idea for 100k ids? i'm new to programming so it'll be good idea if you provide sone code solution.